# Business model based on commission charging

Tags: single-word-requests, business-language

I'd like to know the correct expression to point out the essence of this business model. I'm talking about web servers that gather users (offering and consuming services) and that charge them commissions based either on just having an account or per service provided.

example:

- $10 a month for your membership - then provide you services on youtself
- account is free, but we want 10% of your revenue from provided services

According to dictionaries, "commissioning" doesn't have the meaning coming from "commission" so that I can't call it "Models based on commissioning" . What is the right word/expression or name of this web business model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about "**Commission-based model**"?

Comment: It sounds good, that's what I would use, but I'd like to be sure, that there isn't any other expression, that would be more "from books" :-) I'll wait for some other opinions. Thanks

Comment: Cool. I want to see other words for that too.

Comment: Even just "commission model" is fine. For example, "This business raises revenue using a commission model. Customers pay a fixed percentage of their gross sales ..."